# Why are my Supabase queries returning an inconsistent number of rows?

Tags: javascript, next.js, supabase

When I select by columns, it correctly returns the columns in all four rows of my table. If I select all columns and all rows, it only returns two of the four rows.

The number of rows returned depends on my query. For example, calling

```
let { data: shows, error } = await supabase.from('shows').select('');
console.log(shows);
```

returns

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    created_at: '2024-02-14T16:20:20.259617+00:00',
    city: 'Denver',
    state: 'CO',
    date: '2024-03-14',
    time: '22:19:15-06',
    address: 'Theater',
    img_url: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598805291212-f1e476b437df?q=80&w=1000&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTZ8fHNob3d8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D',
    purchase_link: 'https://www.google.com/'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    created_at: '2024-02-18T23:18:41.024218+00:00',
    city: 'Iowa City',
    state: 'IA',
    date: '2024-03-26',
    time: '22:00:00-06',
    address: 'Gabes',
    img_url: 'null',
    purchase_link: 'null'
  }
]
```

Calling `let { data: shows, error } = await supabase.from('shows').select('');`
Returns `{ state: 'CO' }, { state: 'IA' }, { state: 'CA' }, { state: 'CA' }` .

Shouldn't querying all rows and all columns return all items? If I query by city, it only returns one city. I don't understand the inconsistency at all and would love some explanation.

Comment: You seem to have made a mistake in your question as both of your sample queries are the same.